# Extract Google Drive zip from Google colab notebook

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, zip

I already have a zip of (2K images) dataset on a google drive. I have to use it in a ML training algorithm.
Below Code extracts the content in a string format:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
import io
import zipfile
# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
# This only needs to be done once per notebook.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Download a file based on its file ID.
#
# A file ID looks like: laggVyWshwcyP6kEI-y_W3P8D26sz
file_id = '1T80o3Jh3tHPO7hI5FBxcX-jFnxEuUE9K' #-- Updated File ID for my zip
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
#print('Downloaded content "{}"'.format(downloaded.GetContentString(encoding='cp862')))
```

But I have to extract and store it in a separate directory as it would be easier for processing (as well as for understanding) of the dataset.

I tried to extract it further, but getting "Not a zipfile error"

```
dataset = io.BytesIO(downloaded.encode('cp862'))
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(dataset, "r")
zip_ref.extractall()
zip_ref.close()
```

[Google Drive Dataset](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfuMMGafmiZ35alIgYkZeyGkR6gHhBURjxJPSe6aB6CWjN1EA/viewform)

Note: Dataset is just for reference, I have already downloaded this zip to my google drive, and I'm referring to file in my drive only.

Answer (score 127):

You can simply use this

```
!unzip file_location
```

Comment: @zeeshan how can i specify output directory ?

Comment: Specify it next to the `file_location`.

Answer (score 99):

TO unzip a file to a directory:

```
!unzip path_to_file.zip -d path_to_directory
```

Comment: Works great. Fast. 
Example !unzip drive/MyDrive/feedback-prize-2021/train.zip -d drive/MyDrive/feedback-prize-2021/train/

Answer (score 29):

To extract Google Drive zip from a Google colab notebook:

```
import zipfile
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive/')

zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("/content/drive/My Drive/ML/DataSet.zip", 'r')
zip_ref.extractall("/tmp")
zip_ref.close()
```

Comment: How much time does it take for the files to reflect in the destination directory? My zip file size is around 10 gb

Comment: This code snippet is not generating output at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was trying to unzip in a shared folder location. Issue was resolved when I used the absolute path.

Answer (score 24):

If you are dealing with a zip file, like for me it is mostly thousands of images and I want to store them in a folder within the drive, then do this --

`!unzip -u "/content/drive/My Drive/folder/example.zip" -d "/content/drive/My Drive/folder/NewFolder"`

`-u` part controls extraction only if new/necessary. It is important if suddenly you lose connection or hardware switches off.

`-d` creates the directory and extracted files are stored there.

Of course before doing this you need to mount your drive

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I hope this helps! Cheers!!

Comment: Hi @Suvo, the link for colab's "notebook" is dead. If you can replace it with the new link it would be useful. If the link is obsolete, please update the answer as seems appropriate.

Comment: @HarshaJK Thanks for pointing that out. Removed

Answer (score 9):

First, install unzip on colab:

```
!apt install unzip
```

then use unzip to extract your files:

```
!unzip  source.zip -d destination.zip
```

Comment: what if the file is protected with a password? I tried to add -pPassword   but it does not work, I found this error "caution: filename not matched: MyPassword"

Answer (score 9):

Please use this command in google colab

Unzip the file you want to extract and then the location

```
!unzip "drive/My Drive/Project/yourfilename.zip" -d "drive/My Drive/Project/yourfolder"
```

Answer (score 7):

Mount GDrive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Open the link -> copy authorization code -> paste that into the prompt and press "Enter"

Check GDrive access:

```
!ls "/content/gdrive/My Drive"
```

[Unzip](https://superuser.com/questions/100656/linux-unzip-command-option-to-force-overwrite) (q stands for "quiet") file from GDrive:

```
!unzip -q "/content/gdrive/My Drive/dataset.zip"
```

Comment: for unzip isn't it I/O-wise better to first copy the zip file to local Colab storage then do the unzip operation?

Answer (score 6):

First create a new directory:

```
!mkdir file_destination
```

Now, it's the time to inflate the directory with the unzipped files with this:

```
!unzip file_location -d file_destination
```

Answer (score 5):

For Python

Connect to drive,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Check for directory

`!ls`
 and `!pwd`

For unzip

```
!unzip drive/"My Drive"/images.zip
```

Comment: For the code part, please use the language-specific format ( it's Python in this context).

Comment: Have added, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

After mounting on drive, use [shutil.unpack_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive). It works with almost all archive formats (e.g., “zip”, “tar”, “gztar”, “bztar”, “xztar”) and it's simple:

```
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive("filename", "path_to_extract")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for large datasets. I have tried it on a 60GB zip file, but it didn't work out!

Comment: It's not a problem with shutil; Colab RAM does not have the capacity to hold your 60 GB zip file in the first place.

Comment: I got 35GB ram, and I think that is sufficient. I think it doesn't load the whole file to the memory. I don't know but in my local system with 8GB I have extracted more than 50GB without any issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me.

```
!apt install unzip
```

Then I used this code to unzip the file

```
!unzip /content/file.zip -d /content/
```

Without installing `unzip` on Colab first you'll always receive error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `GetContentString()`, use  GetContentFile() instead. It will save the file instead of returning the string.

```
downloaded.GetContentFile('images.zip')
```

Then you can unzip it later with `unzip`.

Comment: It seemed to work, but was too fast perhaps.  But then unzip didn't work.

Archive:  flowers.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of flowers or
        flowers.zip, and cannot find flowers.ZIP, period.

Answer (score 1):

SIMPLE WAY TO CONNECT

1) You'll have to verify authentication

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
```

2)To fuse google drive

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
```

3)To verify credentials

```
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

4)Create a drive name to use it in colab ('gdrive') and check if it's working

```
!mkdir gdrive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse gdrive
!ls gdrive
!cd gdrive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!unpack file.zip
```

If its now working or file is 7z try below

```
!apt-get install p7zip-full
!p7zip -d file_name.tar.7z
!tar -xvf file_name.tar
```

Or

```
!pip install pyunpack
!pip install patool

from pyunpack import Archive
Archive(‘file_name.tar.7z’).extractall(‘path/to/’)
!tar -xvf file_name.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

We assumed that you're already mounting your googleDrive to googleColab. in case if you just want to extract zip file thats contains .csv extention. just call pandas attribute read_csv

```
pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/folder/example.zip')
```

Answer (score -2):

in my idea, you must go to a certain path for example:

> from google.colab import drive drive.mount('/content/drive/') cd
> drive/MyDrive/f/

**then :**

!apt install unzip
!unzip zip_folder.zip -d unzip_folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxZMG.jpg)