# How to unzip a file in a specific folder in colaboratory environment after download it?

Tags: python, tar, google-colaboratory

I've looking for a solution to solve the slow upload speed of images dataset on google colab when i use a connection from GoogleDrive. Using the follow code:

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Using this procedure i can upload images and create labels using a my `def load_dataset`:

`'train_path=content/gdrive/MyDrive/Capstone/Enviroment/cell_images/train'`

`train_files, train_targets = load_dataset(train_path)`

But, as i said, it's very slow, especially because my full dataset is composed by 27560 images.

To solve my problem, i've tried to use [this solution](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-transfer-large-files-to-google-colab-and-remote-jupyter-notebooks-26ca252892fa).

But now, in order to still use my `def`function, after download the `.tar` file i wanna extract in a specific folder in the colab enviroment. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685924/extract-google-drive-zip-from-google-colab-notebook) but not solve my problem.

Example:

This is the environment with the test.tar already downloaded.
[image]

But i wanna extract the files in the tar file, which structure is `train/Uninfected` ; `train/Parasitized`, to get this:

- content

  - cell_images

    - test

      - Parasitized
      - Uninfected
    - train

      - Parasitized
      - Uninfected
    - valid

      - Parasitized
      - Uninfected

To use the path in def function:

`train_path = train_path=content/cell_images/train/'`

`train_files, train_targets = load_dataset(train_path)`

`test_path = train_path=content/cell_images/test/'`

`test_files, test_targets = load_dataset(test_path)`

`valid_path = train_path=content/cell_images/valid/'`

`valid_files, valid_targets = load_dataset(valid_path)`

I tried to use:
`! mkdir -p content/cell_images`
and 
`!tar -xvf 'test.tar' content/cell_images`

But it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To extract the files from the tar archiver to the folder `content/cell_images` use the command-line option `-C`:

```
!tar -xvf  'test.tar' -C 'content/cell_images'
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

Although late answer, but might help others:

[shutil.unpack_archive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.unpack_archive) works with almost all archive formats (e.g., “zip”, “tar”, “gztar”, “bztar”, “xztar”) and it's simple:

```
import shutil
shutil.unpack_archive("filename", "path_to_extract")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!tar -xvf "cord-19_2021-12-20.tar.gz"
```

as given here also
https://colab.research.google.com/github/sudo-ken/compress-decompress-in-Google-Drive/blob/master/Unrar_Unzip_Rar_Zip_in_GDrive.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Connect to drive,

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

Check for directory
!ls and !pwd

unzip
!unzip drive/"My Drive"/images.zip -d destination

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is the default directory, `/content`, you can unzip your folder project like this:

```
%%bash
mkdir foldername
tar -xvf '/content/foldername.tar' -C '/content/'
```

`%%bash` lets you script without using `!` at the beginning of each line.