# How to unzip a folder passing a variable?

Tags: python, bash, unzip, google-colaboratory

I am trying to unzip a folder by passing it a variable in Google-colab. However when I do it, it doesn't show up in my folders.

If I do it by passing it directly the name, like in this answer here: 
[Extract Google Drive zip from Google colab notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685924/extract-google-drive-zip-from-google-colab-notebook)

```py
!unzip TASI.zip
```

I get this output:

```py
rchive:  TASI.zip
  inflating: TASI/Output [11-13(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 15_58_09].csv  
  inflating: TASI/Output [11-15(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 15_51_26].csv  
  inflating: TASI/Output [11-46(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 15_41_08].csv  
  inflating: TASI/Output [11-47(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 15_36_31].csv  
  inflating: TASI/Output [3-14(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 14_06_52].csv  
  inflating: TASI/Output [3-18(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 13_55_35].csv  
  inflating: TASI/Output [4-31(1) _bad_; 18_06_2019 14_51_19].csv
```

And the folder appears in my colab files.

If I do it by passing it the variable:

```
file_folder="TASI.zip"
!unzip -c "$file_folder"
```

In the output it shows me the content of every file. And the folder does not appear in the colab files. Output:

```
Archive:  TASI.zip
  inflating: TASI/Output [11-13(1) _good_; 18_06_2019 15_58_09].csv  
﻿
SetupTitle, Output
PrimitiveTest, I/V Sweep
TestParameter, Context.MainFrame, 4155C
TestParameter, Channel.UnitType, SMU, SMU, SMU
TestParameter, Channel.Unit, SMU3:MP, SMU4:MP, SMU1:MP
TestParameter, Channel.IName, ID, IS, IG
TestParameter, Channel.VName, VD, VS, VG
TestParameter, Channel.Mode, V, COMMON, V
TestParameter, Channel.Func, VAR1, CONST, VAR2....
```

How do I unzip the folder in colab passing it a variable?

Comment: you are not running exactly the same command so why you expect them to work the same? have you checked what the "-c" flag does? from my understanding it tells unzip to unzip the files to STDOUT/screen rather than to a folder

Comment: Taking the "-c" out fixed it. I had taken the code online from someone trying to pass a variable, I guess they were using it In a different way than I am. 
thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-c` flag to unzip is defined as `extract files to stdout/screen (''CRT'').` the two commands you are running are not the same, in the command where you specifically provide the file name you dont use the -c option so unzip extracts to the filesystem. In the command where you give a variable you use the -c flag telling unzip just to extract the files to the screen.

Try unzip with the variable but without the -c flag.

```
file_folder="TASI.zip"
!unzip "$file_folder"
```